# Convert (x, y) coordinate into (r, g, b) values

Tags: javascript, colors

Hello wizards of Stack Overflow,

I've been tasked with plotting some data onto a scatter chart in Javascript, but with a twist! These plotted objects need to follow a strict colour code. I've got the plotting part right, but the colour generation has me stumped. The graph follows a maximum value x and y of 100 and a minimum value of zero (I'm dealing with percentages).

The bottom left corner of the graph should be pure green and the diagonal top right should be pure red with a hazy yellow-orange in the middle. E.g. point (0, 0) should be (red:0 green:255 blue:0), point (100, 100) should be (red:255 green:0 blue:0) and point (50, 50) should be (red:132 green:132 blue:20).

So basically there's a diagonal gradient of green to red running from point (0, 0) to point (100, 100).

```
|         red
|       /
|     /
| green
```

Has anyone dealt with a similar situation and perhaps has some sort of algorithm to figure this out?

Regards,
JP

Comment: could you tell us also what happens when you have (0, 100) or (100, 0)?

Comment: This is more of a math problem than a programming problem. Also note that there are many ways to map a 2D space to a 3D space (or 2D space if you are only using R and G). What you can do is [rotate your point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_(mathematics)#Two_dimensions) by pi/4, and put the y value into [lerp(green, red, y)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think I can envision what you want to plot exactly, but I think you can solve a lot of things when you split your r, g and b values into different functions.
So instead of func_rgb(x, y) {...} you should make three different functions - one for each color channel - that you can manipulate individually and add the results up afterwards.

```
func_r(x,y) {
    return x/100 * 256;
}

func_g(x,y) {
    return (1 - x/100) * 256;
}

func_b(x,y) {
    return (1 - (0.5 - x/100)^2) * 20;
}
```

I know these functions only contain the X-value, however, I think you can figure out the rest of the math on your own.

Answer (score 0):

From the information I have so far, the easiest way to deal with this would be:

- Green = 255 - ((255/100)*((x+y)/2))
- Red = ((255/100)*((x+y)/2))

This way, if you were at (0, 0) you'd have:

- Green = 255 - ((255/100)*((0+0)/2)) = 255
- Red = ((255/100)*((0+0)/2)) = 0

Or if you were at (13, 13):

- Green = 255 - ((255/100)*((13+13)/2)) = 222
- Red = ((255/100)*((13+13)/2)) = 33

It's important to mention that blue seems not to be relevant, and I don't know what should happen if x and y are very different, so I just calculated the mean.

Answer (score 0):

If the lower left corner is completely green (in rgb `(0, 255, 0)`) and the upper right corner is red (`(255, 0, 0)`), that means that the equation for red is `255 / 100 * y` and the equation for green is `255 - 255 / 100 * x`. This way the upper left corner will be `(255, 255, 0)` and the lower right will be `(0, 0, 0)`

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
 <body>
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  <script type="application/javascript">
   // Colours that you want each corner to have
   var topLeft  = {r: 0,g: 0,b: 0};
   var topRight  = {r: 255,g: 0,b: 0};
   var bottomLeft  = {r: 0,g: 255,b: 0};
   var bottomRight = {r: 0,g: 0,b: 0};
   var output = {r: 0,g: 0,b: 0};

   // Perform bilinear interpolation on both axis
   // This just means to do linear interpolation for y & x, then combine the results

   // Provide the XY you need the colour for and the size of your graph
   function getSpectrumColour(x,y,width,height) {
    var div = 1.0 / (width*height);
    
    output.r = div * (bottomLeft.r * (width - x) * (height - y) + bottomRight.r * x * y 
        + topLeft.r * (width - x) * (height - y) + topRight.r * x * y);
    
    output.g = div * (bottomLeft.g * (width - x) * (height - y) + bottomRight.g * x * y 
        + topLeft.g * (width - x) * (height - y) + topRight.g * x * y);
        
    output.b = div * (bottomLeft.b * (width - x) * (height - y) + bottomRight.b * x * y 
        + topLeft.b * (width - x) * (height - y) + topRight.b * x * y);
    
    return output;
   }
   
   var canvas = null;
   var ctx = null;
   var graphWidth = 100;
   var graphHeight = 100;
   
   window.onload = function() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    canvas.width = graphWidth;
    canvas.height = graphHeight;
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    
    var colour = null;
    
    for (var x = 0; x < graphWidth; ++x) {
     for (var y = 0; y < graphHeight; ++y) {
      colour = getSpectrumColour(x,y,graphWidth,graphHeight);
      
      ctx.fillStyle = "rgba("+colour.r+","+colour.g+","+colour.b+",1.0)";
      ctx.fillRect(x,graphHeight - y,1,1);
     }
    }
   }
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```